# Cassandra dying, which coincidences with Spark Runs

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

My Datastax Cassandra cluster of 63 nodes dies once a while (usually with Spark runs). I am not sure how spark queries are making Cassandra nodes to go down.

Can someone suggest ways to analyze this problem.

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Have you done *any* troubleshooting yet?  Also, this is a coding site; I'm not sure how your question applies to writing code.

Comment: Need suggestions on ways to troubleshoot this. A bit new to Cassandra world

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask a bunch of random software developers on the Internet this question?  Sounds like what you really need is a Cassandra expert.

Comment: We have many Cassandra expert users of stack overflow, don't we?

Comment: There might be a few.  They're probably not on *this particular site* to provide Cassandra troubleshooting services, though.

Comment: how many spark workers are you using in parallel? how do they "go down" ? What table are you querying and how

Comment: I know this is offtopic, but I understand right, that you responsible for a 63 node cluster and you havent worked with cassandra yet?